# PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() returns NULL in ECB mode only

Tags: encryption, openssl, private-key, pem

`PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()` returns `NULL` if a private key is encrypted by DES EDE in ECB mode. The issue happens in `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()`:

`4128:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:330:`

If the same private key is encrypted by DES EDE in CBC mode, this function works OK.

I checked, this issue is reproducible on openssl 0.9.8r/y versions (without FIPS). If openssl is built with FIPS the issue doesn't happen.

What causes this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Your question is probably better suited to being asked on the [openssl-users](http://www.openssl.org/support/community.html) mailing list.

Comment: have you made sure to [load the appropriate algorithms?](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html)

Comment: Yes, I call OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(). Also I checked that correct cipher is selected for reading a private key. Looks strange that it works with FIPS only.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Why use ECB mode?  Maybe it's returning null because ECB is insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at OpenSSL sources, this can happen only if padding in encrypted data is invalid. Does this happen with different keys, and can you provide a sample one? And, what tool is used to generate such keys (i.e. the same OpenSSL or not)? Probably, it omits padding/or writes zero padding instead of correct one.